# Passing Variable through function to main()

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# but am learning more and more every day.  Today, I'm trying to build a simple console calculator and need help passing a variable from the function to Main() so I can use it in an if-else to determine what function should execute.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int decision = Introduction();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(decision);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int Introduction()
    {
        int decision = 0;

        while (decision < 1 || decision > 7)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Advanced Math Calculations 1.0");
            Console.WriteLine("==========================");
            Console.WriteLine("What function would you like to perform?");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for Addition ++++");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for Subtraction -----");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for Multiplication ****");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 4 for Division ////");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 5 for calculating the Perimeter of a rectangle (x/y)");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 6 for calculating the Volume of an object (x/y/z)");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 7 for calculating the standard deviation of a set of 10 numbers");
            decision = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (decision < 1 || decision > 7)
                        {
                            decision = 0;
                            Console.WriteLine("Please select a function from the list.  Press Enter to reselect.");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            break;
                        }

        }
        return decision;
    }
```

When I try to use decision up in Main() it says "The name decision does not exist in the current context".

I'm stumped and tried googling it to no avail.

Cheers

SUCCESS!

Comment: Why do you need to share `decision` between both `Main` and `Introduction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the value from `Introduction`.  The value is local to the method and to use it elsewhere you need to return it and assign to a local variable.  Alternatively, you could make `decision` a static class variable, but that's not a particularly good practice, at least in this case.  The `Introduction` method (not a particularly good name, IMO, it should probably be `GetCalculationType()` since that is what it is doing) typically shouldn't have any side-effects.

```
public static void Main( string[] args )
{

     int decision = Introduction();

     ...

}

public static int Introduction()
{
    int decision = 0;

    ...

    return decision;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how that can happen?

Comment: If the above answer doesn't tell you enough to continue, you really need to find a tutorial or book chapter on functions.

Comment: @cSharpNewbie - I've added an example.

Comment: It's telling me not all code paths return a value now.  And Lasse:  I am currently reading multiple books/tutorials.

Comment: Updated.  I'm getting the error that not all code paths return a value.

Answer (score 1):

`Main()` is the entry point for your app. It then calls your method `Introduction()` which adds a new stack frame on the stack. Because you declare the decision variable inside your Introduction method, the Main method has no knowledge of it.

If you instead declare your decision variable outside both methods, you should be able to reference it from either:

```
int decision;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // code here
}

static void Introduction()
{
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `decision` variable in main since it is local to the function  `Introduction`.
You could make `decision` a static class variable but better would be to return the value from `Introduction` and assign it to a local variable in main.